# No more Ajax in the control panel after update to Craft 2.7.0

Tags: updating, auto-updates

I've update a Craft 2 site to Craft 2.7.0 but since I did no Ajax(?) calls work; I can't clear caches, backup data bases, open a Matrix field,...
Anyone got an idea what went wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Gonna close this one as PEBKAC.

Comment: Correct, I was the solution (although it was the first time I had an error with the auto update function in Craft) :-)

Answer (score 2):

Prob solved; I auto updated to Craft 2.7.0 manually, and - stupid me for waiting that long to do that... - I updated it again manually. Problem solved. Case closed